# How to read specific lines from a text file a store them as strings. c#

Tags: c#, string, file, text, streamreader

i want to read lines 4 , 5 and 6 from the text file and store them as separate strings. this is my code which justs prints out each line in the text file.

```
ReadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Eoghan\Documents\Assign02_Data.txt"); 


 static void ReadFromFile(string aTextFile)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader InputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(aTextFile);
        string s;
        while (!InputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            s = InputFile.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keep track of the line number you're reading. If it's a line you want, record it to your string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(3).Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: Huh... Well I never would have known to try this. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Does that _actually_ read the whole file and then do the `Skip` and `Take` stuff or does it actually only read the first 6 lines ?

Comment: It reads the first 6 lines, give or take a buffer's length of extra data at the end.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Compare it with `File.ReadAllLines`. So no, it doesn't read whole file...

Comment: thanks but how do i implement this line into my code

Comment: @EoghanO'Sullivan this is a replacement for all your code.... `lines` has all data you need.

Comment: okay thank you, one last thing if i wanted a string s to be line 4 of text file what would the equivalent code be?

Comment: @EoghanO'Sullivan Are you trying to learn something or make your job to do by someone else?

Comment: i figured out how to o it myself thanks for your help.

Comment: @EoghanO'Sullivan Good for you.... If this answer helped you, see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)